# Is it possible to automatically restart crashed services in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, lamp

I am Using Ubuntu Server and would like to know if it's possible to automatically restart services that go unresponsive. I am operating a standard LAMP stack and occasionally vital services need to be restarted but I want to do it in a programmatic way.

Comment: By "Restart a lamp stack" do you mean to programmatically restart the various services that make up the full LAMP stack? Like restarting Apache and MySQL? Or do you want to automatically restart Linux when it kernel panics? That brings up another point, what do you mean that it's "crashed" - are we talking full kernel panic?

Comment: Yes restart each service programmatically

Comment: I heavily modified your question in an attempt to keep it on-topic and avoid being closed as a shopping question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle services that go into a crashed state, look at [Munin](http://mmonit.com/monit/) and/or the Linux [watchdog daemon](http://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog).

Comment: What does restarting user-mode services have to do with the kernel watchdog?

Answer (score 0):

Supervisord and along the same lines Mozilla Circus are also interesting plays.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to do this.